# do the two code blocks below return the same result? (script element vs div element)

Tags: javascript, html

Do the two code blocks below return the same result?
If so, is there any reason to use one vs the other in a particular case?
Thank you!

Code A:

```
if (document.createElement && document.body) 
{ 
var myscript = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); 
myscript.src = document.location.protocol + '//myURLhere'; 
document.body.appendChild(myscript); 
}
```

Code B:

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.id='dcad';
div.innerHTML=http://myURL;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? The first code will generate `SCRIPT` tag and the second will generate `DIV` tag, so it's a different

Comment: Thanks Iswanto! Besides that, if my purpose is to have the page call out to an external URL, do both of them achieve that? I'm thinking yes, but I'm new to javascript and I'm not sure if innerHTML is better/worse than src in some cases. Thanks much!

Comment: Also, you have to seperate your vars by a comma, not semicolon.

Comment: @walkman: What do you mean with 'call out to an external URL?' Can you give an example?

Comment: walkman: http://api.jquery.com/load/ <-- read that, I think it might help with what you are looking to do.

Comment: @Bram, sorry I didn't follow... where should I use a comma?

Comment: @Iswanto, I want this page to call another .js file located at http://myurl/example.js

Comment: @walkman: do you mean load another .js file? if yes, then maybe you can using your first code.

Comment: @IswantoSan: Yes, to load another .js file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just as I answered in your other post, no.

The `<script>` tag uses a src attribute to point to an external javascript file if desired.

The `<div>` tag does not have a src attribute, and cannot load data this way.

In order to make this work, you need to use AJAX. Then with the ajax response, you could do:

```
div.innerHTML = ajaxResponse;
```

Comment: I see... Thanks David! Can I write the URL as the source of an iframe, and then assign the iframe to innerHTML?

Comment: Yes, div.innerHTML = "<iframe src='http://google.com'>" would work. I would avoid using iframes unless absolutely necesary. It looks like you should do a little reading on AJAX, preferably with jQuery as it does all of this stuff very easily.

Comment: Thanks, David! I'll check out AJAX.